# Installing Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows 10 from USB

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, usb

I made an installation USB with Rufus. On my Lenovo Flex 5, I disabled fast boot and safe boot, prepared unallocated space, and started the installation. After I chose language and keyboard, and connected to WiFi, a message indicated that there was only 2 GB of free space on my computer. This means that the installer doesn't see the SSDD, just the USB stick.

Answer (score 0):

Beore proceeding, do you make sure that you are installing Ubuntu with the same boot options as Windows. This way you will be able to choose which one to boot from in the same boot menu and not worry if one will work or not.